# Custom fields / meta box output

Tags: custom-field, post-meta

I have some custom fields added via a meta box, and I'd like to output them into a dl on the post itself, with the field being the term and the data it contains being the term. Currently, calling `<?php the_meta(); ?>` outputs an unordered list.

Example:

```
<dl>
  <dt>Date</dt><dd>Monday 26 March 2012</dd>
  <dt>Time</dt><dd>11pm</dd>
</dl>
```

I have the meta box fully implemented, it's just the output that I'm clueless with. The relevant part of the meta box code, should it help:

```
function admin_init(){
  add_meta_box("events_meta", "Event Details", "event_details", "post", "normal", "default");
}

function event_details() {
  global $post;
  $custom = get_post_custom($post->ID);
  $date = $custom["date"][0];
  $time = $custom["time"][0];
  $location = $custom["location"][0];
  $tickets = $custom["tickets"][0];
  ?>
  <p><label>Date:</label><br />
  <textarea cols="34" rows="2" name="date"><?php echo $date; ?></textarea></p>
  <p><label>Time:</label><br />
  <textarea cols="34" rows="2" name="time"><?php echo $time; ?></textarea></p>
  <p><label>Location:</label><br />
  <textarea cols="34" rows="2" name="location"><?php echo $location; ?></textarea></p>
  <p><label>Ticket Price(s):</label><br />
  <textarea cols="34" rows="2" name="tickets"><?php echo $tickets; ?></textarea></p>
  <?php
}
```

Thanks in advance for any help! :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use get_post_meta() function to retrieve values of fields.

Example :

To retrieve the value of date metabox use following code.

```
get_post_meta(get_the_ID(), 'date', true);
```

Comment: That worked perfectly in conjunction with an echo  <?php if ( get_post_meta($post->ID, 'date', true) ) : ?>
    <dt id="date-icon">Date</dt>
    <dd><?php echo get_post_meta($post->ID, 'date', true) ?></dd>
   <?php endif; ?>  Thanks! :)